# ActionBarSherlock causes Android Linking Error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I inherited a project that for whatever reason uses ActionBarSherlock even though it was written a year ago... Anyhow, it was written on Android Studio v2.0 and targets android version 19. I updated to AS 3.2 and the build tools to 28, so when I compile I get

`Android resource linking failed: resource android:attr/popupPromptView is private`

It looks like the code that is being generated from Sherlock is trying to access a now private android resource `popupPromptView`.

Looking at the generated files, it looks like it uses it for a spinner

```
<declare-styleable name="SherlockSpinner">
     <!--
         Reference to a layout to use for displaying a prompt in the dropdown for
         spinnerMode="dropdown". This layout must contain a TextView with the id
         @android:id/text1 to be populated with the prompt text.
    -->
    <attr name="android:popupPromptView"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

I'm using the support library for version 19

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
```

So since I kept the android sdk the same even with the updates to the build tools and android studio, shouldn't Sherlock still be able to access the same library features?

I'm going to rip out Sherlock, but is there a way to get around this error for the time being?